# How to authorize API calls made from a mobile app without any registration and login?

Tags: android, api, rest, http, flask

My mobile app does some API calls during usage and some of them should not be possible from anywhere else (e.g. postman)

For instance if you have a database table `user` and a column `membership` and the app-user does an in-app-purchase an API call is made to update that row and change the column from e.g. `standard` to `premium`

Now in theory if someone knows the URL and sends an HTTPS request he could upgrade himself without purchasing anything. I am researching for a while now but feel a bit lost. There is no registration or login. I use the unique hardware ID of the users devices as a primary key to store everything in the database. I thought about something like:

1. When the user opens the app a request is send and the server responds with a randomly generated key
2. All requests the user makes have to use that key which I would send in the header otherwise it gets rejected

Is this the only thing I can do? What is the best practice for a mobile app that does not use any kind of registration?

If it matters I used flutter for the app and flask for the backend that is connected with a postgres database

edit: I am using HTTPS everywhere not HTTP

Comment: If you are using `Google Play Billing`, you don't need to do this. You can simply call the API from the billing library to query purchases. If you still want to use a custom backend for storage, you can obfuscate the URLs, add custom API headers, obfuscate them as well, etc.

Comment: Have a look at OAuth 2.0 Device Authorization Grant, that may be wat you are looking for.

Comment: @BabatundeAhmed He clearly states he does not want any user authentication other than device id.

Comment: @DarShan I am not sure what you mean by "call the API from the billing library". I used RevenueCat for in-app purchases but I do not see any possibility to call the API from anywhere else but the app itself after the purchase. Where do I have to look?

Answer (score 0):

If the api is open as you have described in the architecture then there is no way this can be achieved without having a login mechanism like OAuth or one of those provided by Google Login or Facebook Login. You will have to provide a way for client device to tell you who are you talking with.

Else you can hide this api behind a closed network so that only server can call this api which will only do so after a successful response from the payment gateway. That way you can enable the hit to come only from the specific server ip address.

Also the fact that you want HTTP instead of HTTPS makes this very vulnerable to a number of attacks.

Comment: That's what I assumed. Also my mistake for writing HTTP, I use HTTPS everywhere I will edit that.

But basically without any registration if someone figures out the URL that is sent to the API he can pretty much do whatever he wants and I can't really prevent this